# How to get random top posts from reddit.com/r/showerthoughts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that is supposed to take a random top post from reddit.com/r/showerthoughts and print the title and author of the post.

```
import  random, json
randnum = random.randint(0,99)
response = json.load('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]
print("\n\"" + response["title"] + "\"")
print("    -" + response["author"] + "\n")
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jacks/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = json.load('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]
  File "C:\Users\jacks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Am I on the right track here?

UPDATE:
Got it to work with this code:

```
import  random, requests
randnum = random.randint(0,99)
response = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100', headers = {'User-Agent': 'showerbot'})
result = response.json()
result1 = result["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]
print("\n\"" + result1["title"] + "\"")
print("    -" + result1["author"] + "\n")
```

Comment: `json.load` takes a file pointer as input, it cannot call a url and download the data for you. You need to use something like requests to do that

Comment: So I tried doing this instead: 


`requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]` and my error is now: 


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jacks/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_4.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]
TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: `response.json()` gives you the json where `response = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')` I would suggest reading up on requests docs first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot load json directly from a url, for that you need to use `requests` module.

*Using json module*

```
import  random, json, requests
randnum = random.randint(0,99)

response = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')

response = json.loads(response.text)
response = response["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]

print("\n\"" + response["title"] + "\"")
print("    -" + response["author"] + "\n")
```

*Without using json module*

```
import  random,  requests
randnum = random.randint(0,99)

response = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/showerthoughts/top.json?sort=top&t=week&limit=100')

response = response.json()
response = response["data"]["children"][randnum]["data"]

print("\n\"" + response["title"] + "\"")
print("    -" + response["author"] + "\n")
```

Comment: What does `response.text` do here?

Comment: @Jack `response.text` is to get the response text as a string. `response.json()` will also work, in that case you can avoid importing `json` module.